# Azure Security Center - Would the Monitoring Agent work on AWS and GCP VMs

Tags: security, azure, monitoring, cloud

I'm looking at *Azure Security Center*.  I know it can be used to monitor not just VMs on Azure, but also VMs outside of Azure using an installable Monitoring Agent.

My question is whether this agent would continue to function appropriately if installed on VMs in GCP and AWS rather than on premises?

I don't see any reason why it shouldn't if the VNets for the VMs are setup appropriately.  But is there anything that might stand in the way of this being a cross cloud and on premises monitoring solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the Azure Security Centre agent is designed to be hybrid and used both on Azure VMs and on-prem. In your scenario, your AWS/GCE VMs would just be treated like on-prem ones. So long as you install the agent and the machines can reach the Azure Security Centre endpoints to report data it will all work.